# Facebook API v2+. Open Facebook application (friend profile or chat page) from my android app using intent?

Tags: android, facebook, facebook-graph-api, android-intent

I try to open Facebook Android App (Chat screen) from my own app.

I found that it can be possible using:

intent.setData(Uri.parse("fb://messaging/" + profileId));
where profileId, it's number like this: 100001850642676

But I can't get friend Id in necessary format, because when I'm sending request to get taggable_friends I get friend Id in next format:

AaJcOZygzUbqM4SlA87rxyTuu9d-ZnqJQcbzYcT6YXqjfodxiFtCOS5wGqg2vKHgbtlMSsLx7eEYWzQ0uQA6rYaPxUOUzn-2955PIscLqWPI_A

How can I open Facebook app (chat screen) of friend from my Facebook contact list using Android intent?
OR How to get friend Id in numeric format?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`taggable_friends` is for tagging friends only. Use `/me/friends` instead to get IDs. Of course you can only get friends who authorized your App too, that´s how it is now.

Not sure if it even works with those IDs though, because those are App Scoped IDs and there is no way to get the real/global ID anymore.

More information: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/apps/changelog

Comment: can you have a look at this related question please: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46841489/is-it-impossible-now-to-open-facebook-messenger-chathead-of-friends-from-my-app